# Firefox 4 Issue with jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, firefox4

After upgrading from Firefox 3.6 to FF4 i was surprised to see that  jQuery UI Sortable has stopped working (I am using jQuery (1.4.2) with jQuery UI (1.8.5)) and i get this error (from firebug)

this.helper is null

dev/js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js                   Line 264

I've had a look around but not found any reason for this error. I even upgraded jQuery UI to the latest version (1.8.11) but that did not help.

If anyone has any insight why this is happening (or a fix) i would greatly appreciate your input!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello mtlgray:
I've just tested [jQueryUI Sortable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) with my Firefox 4.0 and it works OK.

Maybe your problem is caused by some misconfiguration in your project.
Please give a try to [FireQuery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firequery/) (for [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)), perhaps it helps you to find out the cause.

Comment: I will give it shot and let you know, Thanks!

Comment: Turns out that i had an issue with jQuery.inArray() within a function that i was using. It was strange as it was not directly giving that function as the error, but got it fixed. Looks like FF4 has fixed this bug (that was in FF3.6).