# jQuery in Firefox 4

Tags: jquery, firefox4

This code was working fine until i went to firefox 4 and now it requires two clicks on the same image for the resize to work? Any thoughts?  Here is the code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideShow a").click(function() {
var imgTitle = $(this).children('img').attr('title'); // Find the image title
$("#thecap").html(' ' + imgTitle + ' ');
$("#lgImage").attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('rel'));
$( ".resizeme1" ).aeImageResize({ height: 372 });
});

});
```

Here is the plugin code in case someone sees something in it?

```
(function( $ ) {



  $.fn.aeImageResize = function( params ) {

    var aspectRatio = 0
      // Nasty I know but it's done only once, so not too bad I guess
      // Alternate suggestions welcome :)
      , isIE6 = $.browser.msie && (6 == ~~ $.browser.version)
      ;

    // We cannot do much unless we have one of these
    if ( !params.height && !params.width ) {
      return this;
    }

    // Calculate aspect ratio now, if possible
    if ( params.height && params.width ) {
      aspectRatio = params.width / params.height;
    }

    // Attach handler to load
    // Handler is executed just once per element
    // Load event required for Webkit browsers
    return this.one( "load", function() {

      // Remove all attributes and CSS rules
      this.removeAttribute( "height" );
      this.removeAttribute( "width" );
      this.style.height = this.style.width = "";

      var imgHeight = this.height
        ,   imgWidth = this.width
        ,   imgAspectRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight
        ,   bxHeight = params.height
        ,   bxWidth = params.width
        ,   bxAspectRatio = aspectRatio;

      // Work the magic!
      // If one parameter is missing, we just force calculate it
      if ( !bxAspectRatio ) {
        if ( bxHeight ) {
          bxAspectRatio = imgAspectRatio + 1;
        } else {
          bxAspectRatio = imgAspectRatio - 1;
        }
      }

      // Only resize the images that need resizing
      if ( (bxHeight && imgHeight > bxHeight) || (bxWidth && imgWidth > bxWidth) ) {

        if ( imgAspectRatio > bxAspectRatio ) {
          bxHeight = ~~ ( imgHeight / imgWidth * bxWidth );
        } else {
          bxWidth = ~~ ( imgWidth / imgHeight * bxHeight );
        }

        this.height = bxHeight;
        this.width = bxWidth;
      }
    })
    .each(function() {

      // Trigger load event (for Gecko and MSIE)
      if ( this.complete || isIE6 ) {
        $( this ).trigger( "load" );
      }
    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Can you go to a machine that has FF3 and see if the code still works?

Comment: It does work in FF3, also in safari, chrome, ie 7, ie 8, (dont know about ie 6 or 9)

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js im calling this file

Comment: I would blindly assume that it has something to do with this plugin `aeImageResize`. Have you stepped through your code using `console.log()` to verify everything is coming through as you'd expect?

Comment: @Seth, still step through the code using console.log() ...?

Comment: how do i use console.log()?  i know that the error console in firefox 4 under tools->error console shows no errors on load or after clicking the images

Comment: basically you would start by checking `console.log(imgTitle);` put it right after you declare the variable. Make sure this is the correct title. Then check `console.log($(this).children('img').attr('rel'));`  to verify your data is correct. Basically you can put anything in `console.log()` and if you have Firebug installed inspect the element and click the console tab. This will save you a million times over with JavaScript development.

Comment: Ive used firebug which is showing no errors or warnings in FF4. Is it possible that FF4 (has issues) that is preventing this from working correctly?

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are working with? It would also help if you can upload your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add ***event*** to your function within your click event

from this (code you posted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideShow a").click(function() {
var imgTitle = $(this).children('img').attr('title'); // Find the image title
$("#thecap").html(' ' + imgTitle + ' ');
$("#lgImage").attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('rel'));
$( ".resizeme1" ).aeImageResize({ height: 372 });
});

});
```

to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideShow a").click(function(event) {
var imgTitle = $(this).children('img').attr('title'); // Find the image title
$("#thecap").html(' ' + imgTitle + ' ');
$("#lgImage").attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('rel'));
$( ".resizeme1" ).aeImageResize({ height: 372 });
});

});
```

noticed the word event in your second ***function()***

did it work?

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try to [FireQuery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firequery/) (for use with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)), maybe this tool could help you to find out the problem.

Comment: Im not that familiary with firebug or firequery but i know firebug is showing now errors while using this code.  Is it possible that FF4 that is preventing this from working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#slideShow a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var imgTitle = $(this).children('img').attr('title'); // Find the image title
            $("#thecap").html(' ' + imgTitle + ' ');
            $("#lgImage").attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('rel'));
            $( ".resizeme1" ).aeImageResize({ height: 372 });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@user520300: Also you can test it in [Firefox 3.6.16](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-older.html) by installing it in a different folder than default one and [managing the two versions in separate profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111920/multiple-firefox-versions-on-same-pc/1111956#1111956) (this example is for 3.0 and 3.5 but you can apply it by analogy to 3.6.16 and 4.0). Don't forget to install [Firebug (1.6.2)](http://outgoing.mozilla.org/v1/18178703a8e05092fda2bc4b50303afd30cf66b8/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/1.6.2) and [Firequery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firequery/) to your FF 3.6.16 too, then by comparing consoles you'll see if there is some FF4 issue that prevents your code from working OK, or it's just a misconfiguration (like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5543862/218717)) that leads to strange behaviors in FF4.

Comment: thanks. Ill try. Not that familiar yet with firebug or firequery so im not 100% sure im following it correctly anyway but ill see if i can notice something between the two.

Answer (score 0):

buddy try to download the latest jquery package and try to use that js file.  I think the problem is FF4 does not properly support old version js files.  I am not sure but you can try.

Comment: OP stated (in a Comment) that he's using **jquery-latest.js**